# TeXShop not finding Gnuplot

Tags: external-files, gnuplot, texshop

I'm working in TeXShop on my mac and I love it.

There is one slight problem though. I use TikZ wich sometimes uses gnuplot to create it's plots. One would think that running TeXShop alone is enough (TeXShop should call gnuplot) but it isn't for me.

I have to run my file from the command line using:

```
latex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

and only after I did this the plot's will appear in TeXShop. What happens is this:

1. TeXShop can't find or call `gnuplot`so it doesn't create the necessary `*.table` files
2. If I call `latex` from the command line, it automagically *does* find gnuplot and creates the correct `*.table` files
3. When I run TeXShop again, the `*.table` files are already there and it just picks them up to work with.

I thought this was normal, until I discorvered it wasn't by using another package that also needs to call an external program (`minted`, which needs pygmentize and/or python). This package works normally from my TeXShop and this got me thinking: should calling gnuplot from TeXShop work just as well?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the location of my gnuplot, using `which gnuplot`on the command line tells me it is in:

```
/opt/local/bin/gnuplot
```

It got installed there using the installtion guide [here](http://gnuplot.darwinports.com/) (actually, I installed *all* the macports, and gnuplot was one of them).

Readings in some other fora lead me to believe the symbolic link is broken.. Although I don't quite know what that means or how to fix it. TeXShop doesn't *know* where to find `gnuplot`.

What should I do to fix this?

PS: to avoid the obvious question: yes, `--shell-escape` is enabled in my TeXShop preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either tell TeXShop to use `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot` instead of `gnuplot`, or add `/opt/local/bin` to the `PATH` that graphical applications see under Mac OS X. For the latter, you should have to edit (or create) the file `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`, see http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/AquaEnvVar.html.

The following should work in your case, but make sure you also add the directory where the tex binaries live

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>PATH</key>
<string>/opt/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Don't forget to logout and login again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Hi for me it was not nessasary to add a plist-path. Adding the path to $PATH by editing local .bashrc did work fine for me. Open .bashrc and add `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin`

Comment: in `~` wich is also konwn as `/Users/yournamehere/` if `bashrc` resp. `.bash_profile` is not there you may create it. Remember: files beginning with `.` are hidden files you need to say `ls -a` to get them listed. If `.bash_profile ` is present, everything else is ignored. Depending on your configuration it might be necessary to set the PATH either in `.bash_profile`or `profile` or another rc-file. Per defualt you should find a `.bas_profile` in your home-dir. If so, try to set your PATH here. Sometimes its helpful to add a `echo "This is .bash_profile read in!"` on top of the file.

Comment: @bloodworks thanks, but it worked using cefstats' method.

It didn't work just adding the lines though, I had to input the stuff between `<string>` and `</string>` using the mac os plist editor.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to create a symbolic link so that TeXShop finds it in the place it's looking.  In a Terminal window execute:

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/gnuplot /usr/local/bin
```

(the `$` is the prompt, not something to execute.)

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work. Might be I did something wrong though.

Comment: At the time I had this problem I tried modifying the $PATH and it didn't work for me.  But like you, I may have been doing something wrong. `:-D`