pgfplots: How to fill a 'contour lua' f(x,y) plot
I drew a curve (as seen here) with contour lua. 
But how can I fill the curve (with lightblue)?

% !TeX LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=ln((1+\x)^2+\y^2)
     +ln((1+(7*\x)/2)^2+(49*\y^2)/4)
          +ln((1+4*\x)^2+16*\y^2);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
enlargelimits, 
]
\addplot3[
contour lua={
%number=1, % this
levels={1},% or that
labels=false,
handler/.style=smooth,
draw color=blue, 
},
domain=-2:0.5,
samples=66,% will last longer...
thick, 
%fill=red,  % does not work
]{f(\x,\y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=ln((1+\x)^2+\y^2)+ln((1+(7*\x)/2)^2+(49*\y^2)/4)+ln((1+4*\x)^2+16*\y^2);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
enlargelimits,
colormap={CM}{color=(blue!50) color=(white)},
]
\addplot3[
contour filled={levels={1}},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
]{f(\x,\y)};
\addplot3[
contour lua={levels={1}, labels=false, draw color=blue},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
thick, 
]{f(\x,\y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Beware: Viewer Limitations The following paragraph makes uses of pdf
features which are un- supported by some free viewers (including
pdf.js and evince). Please resort to a suitable viewer if you see
unexpected results.

Edit: Thanks to @cis for leading to this solution that should not have the same viewer limitations. I initially did not think that contour gnuplot would create data as a curve (prepared contour) -but it does. The same solution could be used for more than one contour, but filtering would be needed.
To compile, you need gnuplot installed and compile with --shell-escape : What does --shell-escape do?
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=ln((1+\x)^2+\y^2)+ln((1+(7*\x)/2)^2+(49*\y^2)/4)+ln((1+4*\x)^2+16*\y^2);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
enlargelimits,
]
\addplot3[
draw=none, forget plot,
contour external/file={temp_contour},
contour gnuplot={levels={1}, labels=false},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
]{f(\x,\y)};
\addplot3[blue, thick, fill=blue!50] table {temp_contour.table} -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Yes, becomes nice and smooth, if I set samples=20,  samples y=88, at contour lua; very good.

Even compiling in LuaLaTeX, the fill never smooths up for me even using 200 for both samples. :-(

@JohnD: See warning from the manual that I quoted. Try Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Ah OK, I just looked at the result in the PDF viewer of the TeXworks editor (everything is fine there). But it looks blurry in the Chrome browser. I don't know, but I suspect that 'contour fill' doesn't work perfectly with 'contour lua'. A solution could be to do without both and to create the filling with 'contour gnuplot'; But I don't know enough about the gnuplot commands to do that.

contour fill works perfectly with contour lua - see the above code. It makes absolutely no difference if you choose to use contour gnuplot instead. (contour gnuplot can not create filled contours).

@hpekristiansen Yes I know. But maybe one can make something like an \addplot gnuplot {...}; of this, but I can't.
`

gnuplot does not help with anything here . Of course one can manually figure out the function of the shape and make a filled plot, but gnuplot is not needed for that. Edit: I am now not sure - if you could figure out a way to make gnuplot generate a table for the contour and then use that for a fill, it might work - I will think some more.

@hpekristiansen Sorry, I didn't understand the "Beware" message. You are correct: when I open the pdf in Acrobat, it looks just fine. Thank you!

@JohnD: See also my edit.

I installed 'gnuplot' today, but % arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes } seem to does not create  temp_contour.table -->
! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{temp_contour.table} could not be ope ned.

I do not know what arara is - I can not help. I believe first step is to be able to compile simple code that uses gnuplot - either from the manual or other questions on this site. Next step is to use a file browser to see if the file temp_contour.table exists. If that works, the file might not be accessible - check if you can plot other files. -beware of rights and paths.

Yes, it creates temp_contour.dat but not temp_contour.table. arara (written by PauoloCereda) should make the same as pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex; which I tested too, same error.

gnuplot is not running - you need to look up how to make it work on your system.

@hpekristiansen Seems you are right. I don't understand: if I use the gnuplot-command manually it works (at simple examples). But I do not know what pgfplots does here.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/texshop-not-finding-gnuplot
